# Slaptest, bad configuration file

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, kerberos

I have been struggling to start LDAP server and I am failing miserably at it, from journalctl -xn I it clearly say bad configuration files!,
but there are three configuration files, but what is missing/wrong.

I do not have a clue.(Noob QA guy, with little experience in setting up server of any kind, taken this responsibility to test a product which requires kerberos+LDAP setup)

## 1:olcDatabase={0}config.ldif

```
   1 # AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
   2 # CRC32 5b8d3eae
   3 dn: olcDatabase={0}config
   4 objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
   5 olcDatabase: {0}config
   6 olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
   7  ,cn=auth" manage by * none
   8 structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
   9 entryUUID: c1537b28-ed16-1034-9396-7188a52812eb
  10 creatorsName: cn=config
  11 createTimestamp: 20150911212105Z
  12 entryCSN: 20150911212105.249119Z#000000#000#000000
  13 modifiersName: cn=config
  14 modifyTimestamp: 20150911212105Z
  15 olcRootPW: {SSHA}WJTAm3glD5O87VKlhz5v3u4+1A3MVB8E
```

## 1:olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif

```
   1 # AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
   2 # CRC32 e5f82fb5
   3 dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor
   4 objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
   5 olcDatabase: {1}monitor
   6 olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
   7  ,cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=ixsystems,dc=com" read by * none
   8 structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
   9 entryUUID: c153c754-ed16-1034-9397-7188a52812eb
  10 creatorsName: cn=config
  11 createTimestamp: 20150911212105Z
  12 entryCSN: 20150911212105.251069Z#000000#000#000000
  13 modifiersName: cn=config
  14 modifyTimestamp: 20150911212105Z
```

## 1:olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif

```
   1 # AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
   2 # CRC32 2e34b404
   3 dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb
   4 objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
   5 objectClass: olcHdbConfig
   6 olcDatabase: {2}hdb
   7 olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
   8 olcSuffix: dc=ixsystems,dc=com
   9 olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=ixsystems,dc=com
  10 olcRootPW: {SSHA}WJTAm3glD5O87VKlhz5v3u4+1A3MVB8E
  11 olcDbIndex: objectClass eq,pres
  12 olcDbIndex: ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname eq,pres,sub
  13 structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
  14 entryUUID: c153cf4c-ed16-1034-9398-7188a52812eb
  15 creatorsName: cn=config
  16 createTimestamp: 20150911212105Z
  17 entryCSN: 20150911212105.251273Z#000000#000#000000
  18 modifiersName: cn=config
  19 modifyTimestamp: 20150911212105Z
  20 olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=ixsystems,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by * none
  21 olcAccess: {1}to * by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=ixsystems,dc=com" write by self write by * read
```

## [root@qa-ldap-kerb cn=config]# journalctl -xn

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2015-09-13 04:31:08 EDT, end at Mon 2015-09-14 20:17:13 EDT. --
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb slapd[4348]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.39 (Mar  6 2015 04:35:49) $
                                                  mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.39/openldap-2.4.39/servers/slapd
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb slapd[4348]: ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif"
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb slapd[4348]: ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb slapd[4348]: ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif"
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb slapd[4348]: str2entry: entry -1 has no dn
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb slapd[4348]: slapd stopped.
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb slapd[4348]: connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slapd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 14 20:17:13 qa-ldap-kerb systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the CRC lines, and don't edit these files by hand ever again. Use an LDAP browser.